# jq - Create JSON object map from environment variables

Tags: json, object, key, command-line-interface, jq

I am using jq 1.5 and trying to pass two environment variables via jq to create a json object:

```
export REGIONS="region1,region2"
export KMS_KEYS="key1,key2"
```

test.json

```
{
    "builders": [
    {
      "name": "aws"
    }
  ]
}
```

using the following command:

```
jq --arg regions $REGIONS --arg kmskeys $KMS_KEYS '.builders[].region_kms_key_ids={$regions}' test.json
```

current outcome:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "name": "aws",
      "region_kms_key_ids": {
        "regions": "region1,region2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

desired outcome:

```
{
    "builders": [
    {
      "name": "aws",
      "region_kms_key_ids": {
        "region1": "key1",
        "region2": "key2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm stuck on how to use my REGIONS variable content as the keys and KMS_KEYS variable as the values. Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split `$regions` and `$kmskeys` by commas into two separate arrays, transpose them to pair each region with corresponding kms key and make objects out of them, then add them together to form a single object. E.g:

```
.builders[].region_kms_key_ids = (
    [ $regions/",", $kmskeys/"," ] | transpose | map({(.[0]):.[1]}) | add
)
```